# Have Stored Proc with Dynamic SQL that creates loads of results tabs

Tags: mysql, dynamicquery

I have built an SP with Dynamic query code. Trouble is that every time it does something it sends something to a new results tab.  Below is a cut down version of the code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x,z  INT;
    SET x = 0;
    SET z = 0;

    while z <= 9 DO 

        INSERT INTO loop_log (time, note) VALUES (NOW(), z);

        /* Code block 1 - drop tables prior to creation*/
        set @sql= (select concat('DROP TABLE if EXISTS table',z));

        select @sql;
        prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
        execute sqlstmt;
        deallocate prepare sqlstmt;


        /* Code block 2 - create mini visit tables */
        /* Loads of other code blocks */

        SET z=z+1; 

    END WHILE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL p();
```

I really don't want any results tab from the code.

Comment: "it sends something to a new results tab" - Yes, this: `select @sql;`

Comment: If you want no results, go with Paul's answer; if you want the results, but only as one result set, insert them into a temp table and select from the temp table at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure can generate multiple result sets, which will be shown in separate tabs, if you use a GUI client. A result set is send every time you execute a SELECT statement without storing it in a variable with

```
SET @var = (SELECT ...)
```

or

```
SELECT .. INTO @var ...
```

In your procedure the line

```
select @sql;
```

will be exected in every loop iteration and a result set will be send to the client. That might be good for debugging - But if you just want to execte the `@sql` statement, without showing it - Just remove that line.

Comment: Hoped it would be something simple!